# Issues with setting bind_ip in mongo on centos, pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Running Mongo 3.0.3 on Centos6.5. Running app with pymongo (python3.4) from a different server.

Can only get connection from remote server to work by commenting out bind_ip completely, which I'm a bit worried about. How can bind_ip be set to accept connections from specific IP of remote server and from localhost?

I tried:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1  # only local works
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1, <remote server IP> # all traffic stops
```

Comment: what if you try to specify only `remote IP`?

Comment: The `bind_ip` configuration value only determines which IP address(es) your MongoDB server is listening to. It does not control access from remote IPs -- that is the job of a firewall. The MongoDB documentation includes some example information on [configuring the Linux `iptables` firewall](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/). I'd also recommend reviewing the [MongoDB Security Checklist](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-checklist/) for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

The `bind_ip` configuration option in `mongodb` is for attaching `mongos` or `mongod` process to listen to specific network interface. As you may know a server may have multiple network interfaces, you may choose on which interface you want `mongos/mongod` to listen for connections.

If I put it simply, `bind_ip` configuration allows attaching `mongos/mongod` process to one or multiple ips that are available on a server so that it will listen for connection requests coming on the specific ip/ips. `bind_ip` sometimes confuses beginers. They may feel that `bind_ip` is for allowing an ip FROM where connections to the `mongodb` are allowed. But this is not true.

For example, suppose you have a server that has 2 network interface i.e `x.x.x.x` and `y.y.y.y`

Now if you run mongod process on this server and use `x.x.x.x` in bind_ip configuration then you can connect to this mongod from anywhere if you use `x.x.x.x:27017` in your connection string. Though the other ip is also on the same server but you will not be able to connect to this mongod using `y.y.y.y:27017` in your connection string. Similarly, if you bind your mongos/mongod to `127.0.0.1` then you will only be able to connect to it from the server itself.

Hope this helps.